# Make: Cannot get pattern rule to work for a PHONY target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile. I am expecting that running `make all` or `make build-target1` would print out "Building..." line. However, this is all I get:

```
$ make -d all
...
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Considering target file `build-target1'.
   File `build-target1' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `build-target1'.
  Must remake target `build-target1'.
  Successfully remade target file `build-target1'.
  Considering target file `build-target2'.
   File `build-target2' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `build-target2'.
  Must remake target `build-target2'.
  Successfully remade target file `build-target2'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Must remake target `all'.
Successfully remade target file `all'.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Makefile:

```
# Define a list of targets
TARGETS := build-target1 build-target2

# Use a pattern rule to define a generic recipe
build-%:
    echo "Building $*"

# Define the default target to build all targets
all: $(TARGETS)

# Define a phony target to avoid conflicts with file names
.PHONY: all $(TARGETS)
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets): `"Prerequisites of .PHONY are always interpreted as literal target names, never as patterns"`.  So your `build-%` rule will never be considered for `build-target1` etc.

Comment: Thanks @G.M.
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! In the same spot it mentions that I should be using : "To always rebuild a pattern rule consider using a “force target” "
Once I added a FORCE then it worked like a charm (I had to remove the patterns from the PHONY part )

Comment: @G.M. Please turn you comment into an Answer for this post. You deserve the credit.